# Handling state changes in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve 3 things with the handleClick() function.  Toggling buttonText to either following or follow, toggling the 'active' class and handling the FOLLOW action. I may not be doing it right. For some reason, the onClick event has no affect for any of this. Any ideas? Thanks

```
class FollowButton extends React.Component {
​
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.state.following_state = true;
  }
​
  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({following_state: !this.state.following_state});
​
    let follow_state = following_state;
    ProfilesDispatcher.dispatch({
      action: FOLLOW,
      follow_status: {
        following: follow_state
      }
    });
  }
​
  render() {
​
    let buttonText = this.state.following_state? "following" : "follow";
    let activeState = this.state.following_state? 'active': '';
​
    return (
      <button className={classnames(this.props.styles, this.props.activeState)} 
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{buttonText}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see errors in console? And i think you need 
onClick={this.handleClick}

Comment: You should see a refrences error in the console because `following_state` is not declared anywhere. I assume you want `var follow_state = this.state.following_state;`.

Comment: No, I am not seeing any errors in the console. Thats the weird thing. React 0.14 needs the click events to use bind()

Comment: React v0.14 does not need it. Using ES6 classes for component definitions need it. And the variable `following_state` not being declared means the code will throw an error and terminate.

Comment: Unhandled promise rejection Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string(…) that is the error I am getting. What could be causing that?

Comment: Actually i am using ES6 and coompile it with grunt, and i write handlers as 
onClick={this.handleClick} 
As i saw bind example in react, if i understand right it is for binding variables into handler, but i don`t see variables here.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried setting the follow_state to this.state.follow_state; but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Did you try to write as i propose?

Comment: A possible reason why it doesn't work is because of accessing state right after it's set, although that should work some of the time.

Comment: @AntonM. In this case hilarl needs to *bind.(this)* to *handleClick* because he's using *this.setState* in there. If not binding, _this_ inside *handleClick* would be the button, not the react component.

Comment: @ArneHugo Ahh that is the reason, ok why not to write handleClick = (event) => {}
Then this should be fine.

Comment: @AntonM. True. Maybe the nicer way to do it, once one gets used to lambda functions ;)

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Felix King pointed out you are using and undefined variable *following_state*. You should define this variable

```
    const following_state = !this.state.following_state
```

and use it to set both state and the follow_status in the action. Do not set state and then immediately call it, as it is not a synchronized call and may or may not be completed in time.

```
    handleClick(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const following_state = !this.state.following_state

      this.setState({following_state}); // You can do this in ES6, as shorthand for {following_state: following_state}

      ProfilesDispatcher.dispatch({
        action: FOLLOW,
        follow_status: {
          following: following_state
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: The click handler does not seem to be firing at all. I just update the code with your solution. I am getting the `error: invariant.js:39 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string` I am not sure if this is related.

Comment: Can you check if your classnames(this.props.styles, this.props.activeState) works correctly? You seem to use onClick correctly.